# Javascript Method Gets Called 3 Times, Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js

As title mentions, this block of code in my testing/learning app gets called 3 times when I run the server:

```js
const createErrorLog = async data => {
  const errorLog = await prisma.mutation.createErrorlog(
    {
      data: {
        ...data
      }
    },
    '{ iruid errorlog irtrackname }'
  );
  const errorLogSearch = await prisma.query.errorlogs(
    null,
    '{ errorid errorlog }'
  );
  return errorLogSearch;
};

createErrorLog({
  //This call happens 3 times for some reason
  iruid: 99999,
  errorlog: 'Why is this happening 3 times?!?'
}).then(errorLogSearch => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(errorLogSearch, undefined, 2));
});
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why?

I have other blocks of code in the same file that have been commented out, these blocks were other learning elements, and none of them ran more than once when called.

I am at a loss.

Comment: Where are you calling "createErrorLog" from?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev I am calling it from a file called "prisma.js" which is imported into my index.js file. Nothing else is in the index.js file. In terms of script wise, it's called directly below the method's init, as laid out above.

Comment: Please give a minimal example I can actually run

Comment: I tested this code in a different dev environment and it ran fine, just once. I went back and tested it again in my original spot and...it works fine now. There must have been an issue in that dev env somewhere. I'm using a V Box to code in so maybe something was acting up? I literally have no idea why it's working as intended now.